# Is it legal that I use Windows 10 without activating it?

Tags: legal-terms

I want to use microsoft Windows as my OS but I don't want to buy it after the Windows trial time expires. According to the microsoft licenses:

Is it legal that I use Windows 10 for years without activating it?

Note: I download Windows 10 iso image from microsoft website.

Comment: Did you buy the software? If so then Microsoft may be trying to get you to agree to a post contract agreement (changing the contract after purchase).

Answer (score 1):

By downloading it you agreed to the terms of the licence. If those terms require activation then by not activating it you are in breach (i.e. acting illegally).